# After adding second monitor to Windows 10, Google Chrome browser opens to a black rectangle

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, multiple-monitors

Everything else seems to be working fine after adding a second monitor to my Windows 10 setup. I can drag application windows from one monitor to the other, for example, and the mouse moves between them OK.

However, when I launch Google Chrome, it opens as a completely black rectangle. Please see pic. Since I cannot see what I'm doing in Chrome, not sure how to approach the problem.

EDIT: Actually, I removed the original video card and monitor and installed different video card and two other monitors.

EDIT2:  I clicked on the top right corner and the black rectangle closed. Now, when I try to open Chrome, it is a white rectangle.

[Google Chrome application window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Exx9.png)

Comment: Is this a desktop or a laptop and which model? Does this happen on both monitors? Try to [disable hardware acceleration in Chrome](https://www.lifewire.com/hardware-acceleration-in-chrome-4125122).

Comment: Did you install drivers for the new card?

Comment: I assumed the card was auto-detected and drivers were applied without me having to do anything, since the NVIDIA dialog (desktop context-menu) let me set the resolution without issue.

Comment: @harrymc: Desktop. Problem on both monitors (Samsung SyncMaster)  Hard to disable acceleration in Chrome when I cannot see what I'm going. is there perhaps a command-line setting to do this?

Comment: Windows does not have the same drivers as from the [NVIDIA Driver Downloads page](https://www.nvidia.fr/Download/index.aspx). Try to download and install your driver, preferably using Option 2 on the page.

Comment: @harrymc: "No certified downloads were found for this configuration". GE Force GT730 for Windows 10 x64. Studio Driver, but they do have a "Game Ready" one.

Comment: Tried twice. Each time data-error when attempting to install the driver. Will keep trying.

Comment: Success.  Thank you. I cannot upvote comments or answers yet.

Comment: On the assumption that you managed to install the driver and this fixed the problem, I have added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows does not have the same drivers as from the
[NVIDIA Driver Downloads page](https://www.nvidia.fr/Download/index.aspx).

Download and install your driver, preferably using Option 2 on the page if you can.
If not, then define the video card and download the software.
Install it and reboot, even if it doesn't find compatible hardware.
In case of a problem, do that while booting in Safe mode.